Show that the series $A_n$ converges
Let
$\operatorname{f}_{n}\left(x\right) = x^{n}\sqrt{1 - x}$ and $A_{n}$ be the area bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $\operatorname{f}_{n}$:

Show that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ converges.
I am stuck with the part of the function that goes to
$-\infty$.
I think I have to get a recurrence but there is allways some $x$ goes to $-\infty$ or $\infty$ and I suggest that all diverges.


Updated:
Hint (almost solution):
Suppose that $f_n(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$. We have to consider $[a,b] = [0,1]$ because $f_n(x)$ has roots $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. So,
$\sum_1^{\infty}A_n = \sum_1^{\infty}  \int_{a}^bf_n(x) dx = (\text{monotone convergence theorem for partial sums $\sum_{1}^N f_n(x)$}) = \int_{a}^b   \sum_1^{\infty}  
 f_n(x) dx  =\int_{a}^b (\sum_1^{\infty} x^n) \sqrt{1-x} = \int_{a}^b \frac{x}{1-x} \sqrt{1-x}dx$
It sufficient to find the last integral (e.g. with Wolfram).

One question regardin the use of monotone convergence. Clearly some of the $f_n$ are not positive from $(-\infty,0]$, is the monotone convergence theorem jsut a matter of absolute values?

In the second equal sign, the order of integration and summation was interchanged, shouldn't we check that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly?

@MiguelCG At first there's a misprint in question, so it makes sense to fix it. At second we use monotone convergence theorem for partial sums $\sum_1^N f_n(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ where $f_n \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$. Hence there's monotonity.

@Morten No, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

@Morten There as was a typo, I wanted to write $\sqrt{1-x}$. Fixed

@MiguelCG Is it all clear now or is it interesting how to find the last intergal?

@MiguelCG now we can show that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$ and then we can change the order of summation and integration.

@Morten But it's not necessary. Monotone convergence theorem works without this condition.

@SergeiNikolaev I think there are two more conditions for the geometric series to be convergent: $a>-1, b<1$

@MiguelCG Whether the question mention the interval we focus on?

@Morten It's mentioned implicitly

@SergeiNikolaev I can deal with the last integral yes, I am just figuring out the previous parts now. Morten, the question just talks about the area bounded by the x-axis and the function.

@MiguelCG Maybe we can split $n$ into two parts: even and odd. When $n$ is odd, the interval should be $[0,1]$; when n is even, the interval should be $(-\infty,1].$

But $f_n$ only converges uniformly when $x\in [-1,1]$, only works for the odd part...$

@Morten I have talked with the supervisor and yes, the problem should only talk about the area from [0,1]

@MiguelCG  I can provide an elementary proof for that.
